# Unable to delete certain files and folders using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to create a script that clears the Lync cache on remote machines.  To do so I need to close Outlook and Lync if they are open, and then clear out two folders whilst deleting another.  Here is what I have so far:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null
$computer = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Which computer do you wish to clear the Lync cache for?", "Computer", "$env:computername")
$username = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer | select username

$RSA = "C$\Users\$username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA"
$Tracing = "C$\Users\$username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync\Tracing"
$SIP = "C$\Users\$username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Lync"


(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName $computer | ?{ $_.ProcessName -match "Outlook" }).Terminate()
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName $computer | ?{ $_.ProcessName -match "Lync" }).Terminate()
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName $computer | ?{ $_.ProcessName -match "Communicator" }).Terminate()

start-sleep -s 3

Get-ChildItem -path \\$computer\$RSA -include * | Remove-Item -recurse -force
Get-ChildItem -path \\$computer\$Tracing -include * | Remove-Item -recurse
Remove-Item -path \\$computer\$SIP\*sip* -recurse -force
```

The script closes the programs as required, but it doesn't appear to do anything with the folders.  The only errors I get are below:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\*myusername*\Desktop\Personal Powershell scripts\Clear Lync cache.ps1:10 char:1
+ (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName $computer | ?{ $_.ProcessName -match  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\*myusername*\Desktop\Personal Powershell scripts\Clear Lync cache.ps1:11 char:1
+ (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName $computer | ?{ $_.ProcessName -match  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\*myusername*\Desktop\Personal Powershell scripts\Clear Lync cache.ps1:12 char:1
+ (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName $computer | ?{ $_.ProcessName -match  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

ISE is open as admin.  I have admin rights to the domain as well as the folders in question.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is the value that is being returned for $username? I suspect that this has the domain in it and it will have to be parsed out.

Comment: I think you're right.  I changed it a little but it still returns the domain name.

`$username = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer | select -expand username`

Comment: I think you're going to want something like this: `(Get-WMIObject -class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer).Username.Split("\")[1]`

Comment: Those look like the WMI is returning nothing and you are then calling terminate() on a null object.

Comment: Nathan Rice, that's exactly what I wanted.  It works fine now.  Thankyou very much.